# Is 50% accuracy on a 4 label multiclass classifier good?

Tags: statistics, multiclass-classification, accuracy

As the title says, I have a classifier with 4 labels.  I am having trouble getting much above 50% accuracy in Predicting labels.

I made sure the data and test sets are made up of approximately 25% of each label, randomly sampled from a bigger data set.

Is this a good level of accuracy?

It is 2x as good as a random guess, but I wish I could get the accuracy higher. If I can’t, is this good enough to use in an app?

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is function of data quality. If the labels are quite similar and you have less data then it's alright for initial phase. To further evaluate your results you could find the prediction results per class using [classifier report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) and see which label class is least performing and then look for better image/text quality or preprocessing to improve the results.